# Alternatives to having nullable columns in primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a forum, where users can subscribe to receiving notifications when new threads are created. They can subscribe independently for each category in the forum. It should also be possible to subscribe to all categories, so that they do not have to specify each category if they want to receive notifications for all categories. (And also so that they will automatically receive notifications for any new categories that might be created in the future.) It is also possible to subscribe at different levels. For example one can subscribe to notifications o new threads only, or, in addition to the notifications, automatically subscribe to the new threads, with the effect of receiving notifications on new posts in the threads as well.

My first idea was to create a table containing `UserId`, `CategoryId`, and `LevelId`, having `(UserId, CategoryId)` as `PRIMARY KEY`. If `CategoryId` is `NULL`, it means all categories. This would allow for a base subscription to all categories, and then one could change the subscription level independently for specific categories.

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| UserId | CategoryId | LevelId |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      1 |          1 |       2 |
|      1 |          2 |       2 |
|      1 |       NULL |       1 |
|      2 |       NULL |       2 |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

The problem is that columns part of a `PRIMARY KEY` does not allow `NULL` values. I could of course use a separate value, such as `-1` as "all categories", but this would break the `FOREIGN KEY` on `CategoryId`. Another idea is to use a `UNIQUE KEY`, which allows `NULL` values, instead of a `PRIMARY KEY`, but then there could be several rows with `CategoryId = NULL` for each user, since `NULL != NULL` in `MySQL`.

A different idea is to create a table using only `UserId` as `PRIMARY KEY`, and `Categories` as a bitmask for which categories the user is subscribing to. If `Categories` is `NULL`, this could mean all categories. This approach does not allow for a base subscription, overloaded by individual subscriptions. Also, the same subscription level is required for all categories, and there cannot be a `FOREIGN KEY` on `Categories`.

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| UserId | Categories | LevelId |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      1 |          3 |       2 |
|      2 |       NULL |       1 |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

Are there any better suggestions for how to solve this issue?

Comment: I would go for a pre-set value for "All" and set both columns as PK

Comment: use composite primary key

Comment: @SmitaAhinave Please elaborate, isn't that what I outline in the first idea?